# Call three forks

Tags: linux, unix, process, fork

```
#include<stdio.h>
main()
{
 fork();
 fork();
 fork();
}
```

Theory says this code will create 8 process. Looking for a simple way to find this?

ps -e

shows only 4 processes when fork() used along with sleep() command.  Is there any simple way to find other than IPC

Comment: I see 8 processes running in ps if I add a large sleep after the last fork. ps seems like a good way to count them to me.

Comment: fork is always 2^n processess!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
#include<stdio.h>
main()
{
    printf("x\n");

    if(!fork()) printf("x\n");
    if(!fork()) printf("x\n");
    if(!fork()) printf("x\n");
}
```

> ./a.out | wc -l

Comment: If you are using Linux, you could also use: 'strace -e fork ./you_program | wc -l', and get 7. Not sure if child processes are in the list.

Comment: `strace -f` to follow child processes